# aws appsync custom subscription resolver: connection failed, runtime error

Tags: javascript, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

What i'm trying to achieve: custom javascript resolver for a subscription.

I understand that when you use appsync and create a type for e.g.

```
type chatMessage { channel: String! userId: String! text: String! id: ID! }
```

appsync will automatically generate queries, mutations and subscriptions for you. And they work, even though the auto-generated subscriptions all don't seem to have a resolver. Why is that so?

[image]

When i try to attach a custom javascript resolver on `onCreateChatMessage`, it failed with
`"Connection failed: {\"errors\":[{\"errorType\":\"Code\",\"message\":\"Runtime Error\"}]}"`.

I tried creating a new subscription, and attached the resolver to it, but it failed too.

The resolver i added was based on the [appsync doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/aws-appsync-real-time-enhanced-filtering.html#aws-appsync-real-time-enhanced-filtering-defining-filters)

[image: resolver code]

[image: appsync console test query]

What am i doing wrong? The logs are not showing any errors either :/

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the same problem. I haven't figure it out but with your example, the doc says to set your Data Source to a NONE type. It looks like you have it set to your mutation's Data Source.